# I tried updating my Live wordpress site to the latest wordpress version (v4.7) and i encountered some issues

Tags: updates

I just tried updating my live wordpress site to the latest version of wordpress and i think the update stopped due to network interruption or something. But now i can't access my wp-admin again.
Each time i type in the URL, it refers me to: http://mywordpresssite.com/wp-admin/upgrade.php?_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2F

Answer (score 1):

If the update wasn't completed, you can finish it manually. Download the latest version of wordpress from https://wordpress.org/download/. After this, remove `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` folders and upload via FTP everything from the archive, except `wp-content`. **Be sure to rewrite existing files**.

To complete the update, go to your `wp-admin` and do the database update.

**P.S.** If there is a `.maintenance` in the root folder (probably public_html), remove it so the site leaves the Maintenance mode.